# Formating of cells with Dates on Exporting

Tags: export, output-formatting, date-and-time, excel, csv-format

I am trying to export a matrix into a .CSV file which has dates with format: Year/Month/Day.

When I try to export it into a CV those cells are converted into Day/Month/Year

When I try to export it into a Excel file those cells are printed as Year/Month/Day (literaly the same thing that is in the matrix.)

I have no argument in the exporting command. I just write:

```
Export["path_to_file.csv", output]
```

The funny thing is that yesterday I think the code was running correctly...

Any idea what is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Please include a sample of the data you are trying to export.

Comment: {{1, "2020/02/26", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {2, "2020/02/27", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issued raised is not a real Mathemmatica issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what happens is the excel changed the formating. If I open the file with notepad it is year/month/day.

Sorry for the trouble.